# Neural Network accuracy is always 0 while training classification problem in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am making a neural network for the titanic classification problem but my training accuracy is always 0. I checked other solutions but couldn't find a solution that works. The loss reduces but accuracy is 0.

```
model= keras.Sequential(
    [
     layers.Dense(10,activation="relu",input_shape=(8,)),
     layers.Dense(10,activation="relu"),
     layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid")
    ]
)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['Accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=64,epochs=200,verbose=2)
```

The input doesn't has any null values.

```
Survived     0
Age          0
Fare         0
Total_mem    0
female       0
Q            0
S            0
2            0
3            0
dtype: int64
```

Here are some of the values showing 0 accuracy.

```
Epoch 1/200
12/12 - 0s - loss: 0.7219 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/200
12/12 - 0s - loss: 0.7028 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/200
12/12 - 0s - loss: 0.6879 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/200
12/12 - 0s - loss: 0.6749 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/200
12/12 - 0s - loss: 0.6626 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/200
12/12 - 0s - loss: 0.6515 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/200
12/12 - 0s - loss: 0.6397 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/200
12/12 - 0s - loss: 0.6272 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/200
12/12 - 0s - loss: 0.6143 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/200
12/12 - 0s - loss: 0.6005 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 11/200
12/12 - 0s - loss: 0.5871 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 12/200
12/12 - 0s - loss: 0.5750 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Comment: Its `accuracy` not `Accuracy`.

Comment: I am voting to reopen the question because the question points to a potential issue/bug in the TF 2.4 code (even though it can be fixed with a simple typo). Check my answer and its comments for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are incorrectly using `metrics=['accuracy']`. Second, this points to a much deeper bug which I think is unintentional. [I have raised an Issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46436) for this on tensorflow repo. Let's hope someone responds.

<s>Keras doesn't identify the metric `Accuracy`</s>. Keras fails to call the MeanMetricWrapper which is required here properly.

---

## Fix for the issue

Fixing that starts showing proper values for the metric.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

X_train = np.random.random((100,8))
y_train = np.random.randint(0,2,(100,))

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
     layers.Dense(10,activation="relu",input_shape=(8,)),
     layers.Dense(10,activation="relu"),
     layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid")
    ]
)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=64,epochs=5,verbose=2)
```

```
Epoch 1/5
2/2 - 0s - loss: 0.6926 - accuracy: 0.5500
Epoch 2/5
2/2 - 0s - loss: 0.6915 - accuracy: 0.5500
Epoch 3/5
2/2 - 0s - loss: 0.6909 - accuracy: 0.5600
Epoch 4/5
2/2 - 0s - loss: 0.6900 - accuracy: 0.5700
Epoch 5/5
2/2 - 0s - loss: 0.6894 - accuracy: 0.5600
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f90e5f7d250>
```

---

## Understanding and tracing the issue

@Mathias Müller brought out a valid concern that if Keras doesn't identify the uppercase metric, then it should throw an error instead of running.

I traced the GitHub implementation to see how the current code works. Here are the steps. (I have linked highlighted lines of code from GitHub repo)

1. During compile, when a metric is passed, the parameter is stored in a [MetricsContainer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py/#L283-L286) object.
2. This container class then calls a function called [_get_metric_object](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py/#L441-L444) from `compile_utils.py`. The job of this function is to take the input and return a metric object of that metric's class.
3. One of the first things this function does is to [check](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py/#L458-L459) if the input belongs to list `['accuracy', 'acc', 'crossentropy', 'ce']` or not.

   - If `YES`, then it directly fetches the classes from the metrics.py and [calls](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py/#L460-L497) the `MeanMetricWrapper` class. The [job of this class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py/#L599-L609) is to wrap a stateless metric function with the Mean metric. This calculates the mean of the metric you have added.
   - If `NO`, then it calls the [get function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L3530-L3571) from metrics.py. The `get` function further calls a [deserialize function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L3511-L3526) whose job is call a function call [deserialize_keras_object](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9cbbc16a2ff969643bbbe474c93430917091ae9b/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py#L340-L344) function from `utils.generic_utils.py`. This function's job is to take the string and retrieve the actual object!

Let's see the 2 scenarios now.

#### Scenario 1: "accuracy"

```
#With lower case accuracy
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.metrics)
```

```
[<tensorflow.python.keras.metrics.Mean at 0x7f90c7ea10d0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.metrics.MeanMetricWrapper at 0x7f90c7d07e20>]
```

Since the metric provided belongs to the `['accuracy', 'acc', 'crossentropy', 'ce']`, the `_get_metric_object` function fetches the `tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy` class and explicitly passes it to the `tf.keras.metrics.MeanMetricWrapper`. This calculates the mean accuracy as expected.

#### Scenario 2: "Accuracy"

```
#With upper case Accuracy
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['Accuracy'])
print(model.metrics)
```

```
[<tensorflow.python.keras.metrics.Mean at 0x7f90e7285e20>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.metrics.Accuracy at 0x7f90e72fceb0>]
```

Something interesting happens here. Since the "Accuracy" doesnt belong to the list, `_get_metric_object` calls the `metrics.get()` ->`metrics.deserialize()`-> `generic_utils.deserialize_keras_object()` function which simply pulls up the `tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy` and returns that directly, instead of calling `tf.keras.metrics.MeanMetricWrapper`.

This is why you get incorrect values for accuracy, but it does not throw an error!!

Comment: What do you mean by "does not identify"? That the code shown by the OP should throw an error?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I am updating my answer with details.

Comment: Updated, took me down a rabbit hole, but glad about it. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Raised an issue as well for the same. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46436

Comment: I am voting to reopen the question because the question points to a valid issue (even though it can be fixed with a simple typo)

Comment: Happy to help, and great analysis of the problem!

Comment: I have also created a `pull request` on the github repo for Tensorflow, with a possible fix. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/46441